# Is there anyway we can create flavored versions of Kotlin Multiplatform build files like dev and prod?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a requirement where I want to have different set of data to be shipped with the library generated by kotlin multiplatform module for different flavors like dev and prod.
In an Android project, we can do with productFlavors in the app's build.gradle.

Is there any similar way of doing the same in Kotlin Multiplatform?

Comment: There are two build types available for Kotlin/Native targets, see [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/building-mpp-with-gradle.html#building-final-native-binaries). Maybe something can be done using [this](https://github.com/yshrsmz/BuildKonfig) plugin. Also, I've seen a [discussion](https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/C3PQML5NU/p1569503173151400) on that in the Kotlin's Slack.